# C++ - Modify a File Without Creating a New File

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a file, and modify some contents inside. My first code looks like this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int status = 0;

    //error if no filename
    if(argc == 1) {
        cerr << "No file specified. Please specify a filename" << endl;
        status = 1;
    }

    //open a file and modify
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        string line = "";
        string filename = argv[i];
        ifstream infile;

        infile.open(filename);
        if(infile.fail()) {
            status = 1;
            cerr << filename << "： No Such File Exist" << endl;
        }
        else{
            while(getline(infile, line)) {
                auto index1 = line.find('(');
                auto index2 = line.find(')');
                cout << index1 << "   " << index2 << endl;
                auto itor = line.begin();
                if(index1 != string::npos)  line[index1] = '[';
                if(index2 != string::npos)  line[index2] = ']';
            }
            infile.close();
        }
    }


    return status;
}
```

I know it's wrong to directly modify `line` because it won't change the content in the file. Is there a way that I can modify the file directly?(Without creating a new file, and output `line` to that)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg since it'll just change '(' to '[' and ')' to ']'' the size should be the same..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Store the lines, modified and unmodified, in a `std::vector<std::string>`.
2. Close the file.
3. Open the file in write mode.
4. Save the lines, stored in the `std::vector<std::string>` to the file
5. Close the file.

It will be better to create separate functions for each step.

```
void readContents(std::string const& filename,
                  std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
   ...
}

void updateContents(std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
   ...
}

void WriteContents(std::string const& filename,
                   std::vector<std::string> const& lines)
{
   ...
}
```

and then call the from `main`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ...

   string filename = argv[i];
   std::vector<std::string> lines;
   readContents(filename, lines);
   updateContents(lines):
   writeContents(filename, lines):
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data you want to change doesn't change the size of the file in any way (i.e. you're not trying to write data that is longer or shorter than the existing data in the file) then yes it's possible, just overwrite the existing data once you find it, by changing the write position.

If, on the other hand, the data is of a different size, then it's *very* hard to do (you need to read everything and reposition it within the file), it's much easier to just write a new file and rename it.

Changing one kind of brace to another will not change the size of the file, so then you can easily do it. Just go through the file one character at a time, when you find a character you want to change, [set the write pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) to the position of the character and write the new character.

Comment: Does it mean it's ok if the file has 80k lines?

Comment: @Kevin217 The current size of the file doesn't matter, it's the size of the new/modified data that matter. If you want to add or remove even just a single character then it's very hard, but if you just want to change one or more character to something else then it's no big deal.